# DynNom + Error: 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector

Tags: r

> fit1<lrm(POPC~Age+ASA+SpO2+RBC+Fluid+imaging+NYHA+Surgery,data=mydata,x=T,y=T)

> DynNom(fit1)
> Error in names(preds) <- allvars[-1] :
> 'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [7]

No missing data, all features are integers. 'names' attibute [8], here 8 means the number of features, if I get rid of one feature, the Error would be: 'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [6].
I don't understand where the vector comes? would you please be so kind to help me to solve this question?